# save terminal log from Gitlab job into a variabl

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm new into work with Gitlab, CI, .yml, shell and Co.

I'm running in my .gitlab-ci.yml this Job

```
- backstop test
- ERROR_MSG='Here Console.Log'
```

And I want to save this Terminal Log, that I see while the job is running in the variabl
"ERROR_MSG""

My question is now, how can I get the Log out of the runner into the variabl?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this: 
It passes the variable by uploading it as an artifact file. 
And GitLab ci built-in functionality will make it available as a variable in the next stage.

```yaml
stages:
  - "build"
  - "test"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "OUT=TEST IT NOW" >> build.env
    - cat build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo $OUT
  dependencies:
    - "build"
```

Reference:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job

This will work for single line values only, if there is a new line this will fail.